# При наведении на блок, все в нем заголовки и параграфы должны поменять цвет без js

Tags: html, css, hover

Такой вопрос:
Есть не большой блок div.price__item, в нем несколько заголовков а так же несколько параграфов и кнопка:

```
<div class="price__item">
   <h1>...</h1>
   <h5>...</h5>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <button>...</button>
</div>
```

Мне нужно что бы при наведении на блок .price__item менялся фон его и цвет всех моих заголовков и параграфов. Подскажите как это осуществить через псеводэлемент :hover

```
.price__item:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #709dca;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Меняется только фон, заголовки/параграфы не затрагиваются почему то

Comment: Видимо, более приоритетные стили есть.

Comment: С !important пробовал, все равно цвета не меняет. Там что то другое, видимо

Comment: Не видя полной картины, сложно сказать. Посмотрите в консоли, какие стили перебивают ваш, для ховера в хроме есть специальная кнопочка `:hov`. Или еще можно попробовать '.price__item:hover * { color: #fff; }'

Comment: Вообще у меня изначально параграфам и заголовкам прописан другой цвет в данном блоке. При наведении на блок тот первый цвет и остается. Новый цвет в :hover не действует. И я вот думаю, как бы сделать так, что бы при наведении он все же менял его в данном блоке.

Comment: Всем спасибо - .price__item:hover * { color: #fff; } - помогло!!!